# Use `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` programmatically (as a replacement for the gcp auth plugin)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I've some existing code that will break on GKE with Kubernetes 1.26 clusters as a result of the change from the built-in GCP auth provider to `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`.

I understand how to revise the code to leverage the `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` binary (see below) **but** I am running the code in a serverless (Cloud Functions) environment and am unable to install binaries and so this isn't a solution for me.

I'm looking to deploy the code as a single binary that can `get-credentials`, and populate an `api.Config` so that the runtime's identity can be used to (repeatedly) authenticate the code to a GKE cluster as I'm able to do currently on <1.26 clusters.

Before I spend too much time trying to work this change into my code, I'm hoping that someone else has already done something similar and can provide a solution or even pointers.

The code uses Google's [Golang Kubernetes Engine API](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/container/v1) to `get-credentials` which it uses to populate an [`api.Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.4/tools/clientcmd/api#Config) which it then uses to interact with a cluster.

```golang
ctx := context.Background()
containerService, _ := container.NewService(ctx)
name := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/locations/%s/clusters/%s",
    clusterProject,
    clusterLocation,
    clusterName,
)
rqst := containerService.Projects.Locations.Clusters.Get(name)
resp, _ := rqst.Do()
cert, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(resp.MasterAuth.ClusterCaCertificate)
server := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s", resp.Endpoint)

apiConfig := api.Config{
    APIVersion: "v1",
    Kind:       "Config",
    Clusters: map[string]*api.Cluster{
        clusterName: {
            CertificateAuthorityData: cert,
            Server:                   server,
        },
    },
    Contexts: map[string]*api.Context{
        clusterName: {
            Cluster:  clusterName,
            AuthInfo: clusterName,
        },
    },
    AuthInfos: map[string]*api.AuthInfo{
        clusterName: {
            [see below]
            },
        },
    },
}
```

The code currently uses the GCP auth provider which enables me to provide a single binary that performs the GCP auth:

```golang
AuthProvider: &api.AuthProviderConfig{
    Name: "gcp",
    Config: map[string]string{
        "scopes": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    },
```

Using the `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` [`client-go` credential plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins) requires a callout to the `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` binary which generates an `ExecCredential` that is then parsed by `client-go`:

```golang
Exec: &api.ExecConfig{
    Command:            "gke-gcloud-auth-plugin",
    APIVersion:         "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    InstallHint:        "Requires gke-gcloud-auth-plugin",
    ProvideClusterInfo: true,
    InteractiveMode:    api.IfAvailableExecInteractiveMode,
},
```

I'm looking for a way to integrate the above `api.Config` construction with the [`gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-gcp/tree/master/cmd/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin) as a library to (continue to use) the (Cloud Functions) runtime identity (via Application Default Credentials) as a mechanism for acquiring access tokens to authenticate the client (code) against the GKE cluster **without** requiring the installation of `kubectl`, `gcloud` or `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`.

The OAuth mechanism underlying GCP auth plugin provider and `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` is unchanged (which helps), I just don't yet understand how to incorporate this into `kubectl`'s new auth mechanism.

###### References

- Google Issue Tracker [How to use `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` programmatically as a replacement for GCP auth plugin](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/263876379)
- [`kubectl` auth changes with GKE 1.26](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke)
- `client-go` [`api.Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.4/tools/clientcmd/api#Config)
- [`client-go` credentials plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins)
- [`gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-gcp/tree/master/cmd/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin)
- [GCP auth plugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/v0.25.4/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp/gcp.go)

Comment: I'm wondering whether the simplest (best?) approach is to simply reimplement a subset of the existing GCP auth plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this v1.26 GKE breaking change and agree that installing `gcloud` (which is few GB large) for a simple Golang `client-go` app is overkill and even unfeasible for containerized apps

Perhaps your approach of reimplementing a subset of GCP auth is the way to go. One such implementation can be found here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/traviswt/gke-auth-plugin

I've just tried the link above and it works beautifully. No need to bundle `gcloud` with your Golang app. Just replace in your kubeconfig:

`command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` -> `command: gke-auth-plugin`

For reference, you can get your kubeconfig via using `gcloud` and `kubectl`:

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <CLUSTER_NAME> --zone <ZONE> --project <PROJECT_NAME>

kubectl config view --flatten
```

Using this as a reference, you can use Golang to generate the kubeconfig with [google-cloud-go](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go) ([Reference that will need modification for v1.26 breaking change](https://www.fullstory.com/blog/connect-to-google-kubernetes-with-gcp-credentials-and-pure-golang/)) and bypass `gcloud` completely